# CSS Class Name selection

Tags: css

My style-sheet looks like this:

```
.caption {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.caption-text {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
}

.caption .caption-text {
    margin: 0.8075em 0.5em;
    line-height: 1.4;
```

**I want to select two classes**:
".caption-text" and ".caption .caption-text"

How do I write the HTML to select the (third) class ".caption .caption-text" without it selecting the (first two) classes ".caption" AND ".caption-text"?

The original HTML I had was:

```
<p id="caption-attachment-1711" class="caption-text">...</p>
```

So it doesn't refer to ".caption .caption-text" but that's selected using a unique id created by CMS. I need to write the HTML without using id!

Comment: It looks like the two props in `.caption .caption-text` should/could go inside `.caption-text` and get rid of the third one. See Erick's answer below and look up the difference of space vs no space.

Comment: That could cause global changes!

Answer (score 0):

If you want an additional style when both classes are put together, don't use a space between it:

```
.caption.caption-text {
  margin: 0.8075em 0.5em;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
```

But it's important to highlight that an HTML element with the both classes applied (i.e. `<p class="caption caption-text">...</p>`) will match the individual classes too. So, all styles of `.caption`, `.caption-text` and `.caption.caption-text` will be applied.

So, lets be clear: **It's the way multiple classes are applied to HTML elements. There's nothing you can do at the HTML side to avoid it.**

So, if you really don't want the styles of `.caption` and `.caption-text` applied, the most obvious and clean approach is to create a third class not related with the first ones, applying just it:

```
.third-class {
  margin: 0.8075em 0.5em;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

<p class="third-class">...</p>
```

But if you're fanatic about your actual class names, it's possible to do some tricks with `:not` pseudo-class to avoid styles of the first class if the second is present, and vice versa:

```
.caption:not(.caption-text) {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.caption-text:not(.caption) {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}

.caption.caption-text {
  margin: 0.8075em 0.5em;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
```

This way, you can have three different behaviors:

- Apply only  `.caption`, the element will have `max-width: 100%` and the `padding: 5px` styles.
- Apply only `.caption-text`,  the element will have `font-size: 0.8em`, `font-style: italic` and `text-align: center` styles.
- Apply `.caption` and `.caption-text` together, the element will have `margin: 0.8075em 0.5em` and `line-height: 1.4` but not the other styles.

But I personally think that a third class not related with the first two ones is by far the best option. Much more readable, clean and maintenable.

Comment: **I'm searching for the HTML**. Are you saying '<p class="captioncaption-text">...</p>' and '<p class="caption-text captioncaption-text">...</p>' will work?

Comment: Hi @NewUser, I just updated my answer to better explain what you can do at the HTML side and what you can do at the CSS side.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the name of third class as .Caption and .Caption-text and these does not affect the other two classes above it, then you can apply this:

1. Change the name of the third class which is .caption .caption-text to

   ```
    <p class="new caption caption-text><p>
   ```
2. Css for third class:

   ```
   .new {
      margin: 0.8075em 0.5em;
      line-height: 1.4;
   }
   ```

   Also, if you want to select two classes at the same time, please use .caption, .caption-text in css as:

   ```
   .caption, .caption-text {
      margin: 0.8075em 0.5em;
      line-height: 1.4;
      }
   ```

   If you want something else, please let me know.